# How to say "To start liking something"

Tags: grammar, adjectives

As far as I know, one can say "I started doing X" by adding X-はじめました。　However, I don't think this applies to "to like", which is an adjective. So how to say for example "I started liking science"

Answer (score 9):

It would literally be:

> [科学]{かがく}が好きになり[始]{はじ}めました。

...using the verb なる(成る;grow/become) and 始める.
But I think you could also say it as:

> 科学が好きになってきました。

...using なる and the subsidiary verb くる(来る).

Answer (score 4):

I think that 好きになった, as in [Chocolate's answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/15880/1628) is the best literal way of saying "I started liking...".

Another very common way of expressing the same sentiment is to use 気に入{い}る. Often translated as "favourite X" in the expression お気に入りのX, when used in the verb form 気に入った it aptly describes that you started liking something, the past tense here pointing at the transition to the "state of liking". So,

> I started liking science.
>   科学が気に入った。

Comment: Interesting that literally that means: entered in caring.